# How to dynamically load a js widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load a news feed widget on file with jquery into a div but it keeps loading only a referral link without the feeds

[example here](http://twisted.plosta.com)

code below

index.php:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#link").click(function(){
         $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url="widget.php",
            data: "id="+1,
            success: function(data){
              $("#show").html(data);
            }
         });
      });
   });

<div id="show">show things will replace me</div>
<a href="#" id="link">Show stuff</a>
```

widget.php:

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="http://www.newsfiber.com/p/s/j?lang=eng&iv=4&r=10&is=60x60C&n=eng&y="></script>
   <div name="_dsnnginf_634080201465X579_" id="_dsnnginf_634080201465X579_" style="font-weight: 400; text-align: left; padding: 0.2em; background-color: #E9E9F0; font-size: 95%; font-family: Georgia,Palatino,Arial,Times,Times New Roman,serif;">
   <a style="text-decoration: none; color: #0000EE;" href="http://www.newsfiber.com/p/s/h?n=eng&y=" target="_blank">
      News
   </a> at 
   <a style="text-decoration: none; color: #0000EE;" href="http://www.newsfiber.com/" target="_blank">
      www.newsfiber.com
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is in _Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened. j?lang=eng&iv=4&r=10&is=60x60C&v=C%2FCulture%2FDesign%2F&n=eng&y=&_=1410456232118:34_. How to fix it (execute script asynchronously) - I don't know, but at least you can start searching from this point.

Comment: Have a look at `getScript()` - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/